# Approach to use for mailbot/chatbot

Tags: chatbot, aiml

This might sound like a general question but I am learning AI techniques/algorithms to implement the best solution for my website to reply to my users. I want to reply to my users as most of their questions over the email are almost the same so I am not sure which algorithm to use to implement my mailbot.
I have been studying `AIML` and apparently it uses best pattern matches and respond with the predefined template thus very less capacity so self learn. Other than this I have started studying basic `NLP` which would tokenize, segment, and then create an answer based on that. Maybe I need some advice on where to look.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Dialogflow for any chat bot applications. Not only does it make ml chat bots easily accessible and free (within a very generous free tier) but also allows you to leverage Google's models and infrastructure with very little development time and effort.

You can even get away with writing zero code, depending on your required integrations or backend.

Dialogflow also allows you to easily implement multiple languages and deploy to many platforms with little in terms of manual work.

It'll be a little more effort than keyword matching but will be a lot more versatile and you'll learn a lot more about intents, context and ml chat bots.

For you to deploy via email you'll want to integrate the API which should be very simple once you have a model configured.